# Put ASP.NET Core WEB API ModelState errors to an array in Angular 6

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a register model in my application as follows:

```
public class UserRegisterDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(12, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "You must specify password between 8 and 12 chars.")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

and i post a register request to server by angular 6 like this:

```ts
  register() {
    this.authService.register(this.model).subscribe(() => {
      this.alertify.success('Registration successful');
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
      this.alertify.error(error);
    });
  }
```

When i post a wrong model to server, ModelValidation works fine and return ModelState errors, but `console.log(error)` shows an object like this:

```
{Password: Array(1), Username: Array(1)}
Password: ["You must specify password between 8 and 12 chars."]
Username: ["The Username field is required."]
__proto__:
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ ()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

I want to put error messages to an array of strings. I try *JOSN.stringify(error)* but it doesn't solve my problem.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily write a function to transform the model errors object into the form you want.  If I understand your requirements correctly then the function below should do the trick.

```
transformError(err: { [key:string]: any }) {
    const messages: string[] = [];

    if (err) {
        for (let key of err) {
            for (let message of err[key]) {
                messages.push(`${key}: ${message}`);
            }
        }
    }

    return messages;
}

register() {
    this.authService.register(this.model).subscribe(() => {
        this.alertify.success('Registration successful');
    }, error => {
        const messages = this.transformError(error);
        this.alertify.error(messages);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Asp.Net Core provides a way of customizing your invalid model state responses.

In your `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection)` method in the Startup class, add the following:

```
            services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
            {
                 object responseObject = context.ModelState.Select(entry => entry.Value.Errors.Select(error => error.ErrorMessage)).Aggregate(Enumerable.Empty<string>(), (agg, val) => agg.Concat(val));
                return new BadRequestObjectResult(responseObject);
            };
        });
```

This will convert your `ModelState` dictionary into the errors array you want.
Please not that you can shape the response in any way you wish other than my `Aggregate` function there.

Your actions will then return `400 Bad request` responses with the errors array in the response body.

Comment: thanks for your help. you and _Daniel Gimenez_  gives me a right answer.